# Realizar o .append(); de um iframe quando a pagina for carregada

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando realizar um `.append();` de um *iframe* que é armazenado em BD.
Bem, tal feito e realizado da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/viatge/auth/getStreetViewCode&${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}',{destinationID: $('#destinationID').val()}, function(data){
        $('#street-view-div').append(data);
    });
});
```

O *callback* irá me retornar o *iframe* completo! Bastando apenas "appendar" abaixo da *div* (`"street-view-div"`).

Existe um detalhe adicional na minha questão. Tal *iframe* irá ser populado dentro de um um *plugin* de "passo-a-passo", logo eu também tentei realizar da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).on('ready', '#street-view-div', function(){
        $.get('/viatge/auth/getStreetViewCode&${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}',{destinationID: $('#destinationID').val()}, function(data){
        $('#street-view-div').append(data);
    });
});
```

A forma acima está obsoleta desde o *jQuery 1.8* se não me falha a memória, logo não funcionou.

Alguém teria um solução mesmo que for paliativa para o meu caso?

### EDIÇÂO

Como sugerido pelo colega André Ribeiro quando o usuário for informar o *iframe* eu irei "desmenbra-lo" afim de armazenar apenas os atributos que convêm para se trabalhar.

Bem, fiz um teste que foi o seguinte. Deixei um frame estático no codigo como abaixo:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="${destinationModify.streetView.embedCode}">
</iframe>
```

Onde o atributo src irá ser populado via parâmetro java. Mas o resultado não foi bem o esperado como mostra a abaixo:

[image: imagem]

Ele simplesmente não carregou o conteudo do frame de forma correta! Sendo que no *DOM* é formado de forma correta!

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&amp;panoid=WritgJx7SbMAAAQJOIX2NA&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;source=embed&amp;output=svembed&amp;cbp=13%2C178.0005991462331%2C%2C0%2C4.175384831223795"></iframe>
```

Já por meio de jQuery acontece ele faz a requisição do atributo src via AJAX e seta o atributo, mas como mostra a imagem abaixo não surti nenhum resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que exatamente não funciona? Não seria mais interessante você já ter este iframe no código e só atualizar o src dele, por exemplo?

Comment: André Ribeiro, simplesmente o iframe não é carregado! Infelizmente vou precisar do iframe inteiro, pois os atributos do iframe vão variar dependendo do caso.

Comment: Da mesma forma como você pode atualizar o src você pode retornar os novos atributos e setar eles no código.

Comment: Bem estou achando que vai ter que ser desta forma, pois com o frame inteiro não vai! Na hora de persistir o frame irei "desmenbrar" os atributos principais armazenar em disco e renderizar com o callback do AJAX. Irei testar e já trago o feedback

Comment: Oi André, desculpa a demora, mas realizei o teste apenas alterando o src via parametro Java e não funcionou. Fiz a edição da pergunta para melhor entendimento.